# The number of syllables in the Rig Veda - 4,32,000

Tags: vedas, rig-veda, yajur-veda, shatapatha-brahmana, numbers

This [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigveda) article on Rig Veda says that there are 4,32,000 syllables in all the shlokas combined. It also says that the [Shatapatha Brahmana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shatapatha_Brahmana) of the Yajur Veda mentions this.

Where is this mentioned? Did they actually count the total number of syllables?

Comment: I think there is also an Upanishad which say this...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, It is true that Rig Veda consists of 4,32,000 syllables. It is verified by Shatapatha Brahmana in 10:4:2:23

> **He arranged the Rik-verses into twelve thousand of Brihatîs** , for of that extent are the verses created by Prajapati. At-the thirtieth arrangement they came to an end in the Paṅktis; and because it was at the thirtieth arrangement that they came to an end, there are thirty nights in the month; and because it was in the Paṅktis, therefore Prajapati is 'pankta' (fivefold). **There are one hundred-and-eight hundred Paṅktis.**

As you can see above, the Rik verses (verses of RigVeda) are equivalent to 12,000 Brihatis. Brihati is a Vedic meter and a Brihati meter consists of 36 syllables. Thus total no.of syllables in Rig Veda are:

**12000×36=432000**

Also it tells RigVeda is equivalent to 10800 Panktis. Pankti is also a vedic meter containing 40 syllables.
Thus the no. of syllables in Rig Veda becomes:

**10800×40=432000.**

Thus, there are 4,32,000 syllables in RigVeda.

Comment: Both questions answered at the same place: 10.4.2 !

Comment: @AmitSaxena yeah it was a lucky chance... in fact I was in search of a standard scripture where it mentions 432000 syllables in RigVeda. .... as this number is related to yuga length also....when I saw this question stating it is in Shatapatha Brahmana... so I began to search in it... and above I also found divisions of 720 also....